# How does MS Word/Excel/etc. change the color of visited hyperlinks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, colors, hyperlink

My question is related to these two:
[What is the style used for visited hyperlink in MS Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/144943/what-is-the-style-used-for-visited-hyperlink-in-ms-word)
[How can I prevent followed hyperlinks from changing color?](https://superuser.com/questions/1084044/how-can-i-prevent-followed-hyperlinks-from-changing-color)

I do NOT want to know how to avoid that the color of visited hyperlinks changes. I have already found the solution in answers to the linked questions above.

I want to know HOW Word / Excel / etc. do the color change.

My ideas how this could be done:

- MS Word remembers the visited hyperlinks in a list and changes the colors based on the content of this list.
  However, I have not found such a list or how to clear it.
  *This is still possible.*
- MS Word assigns the style that is set for visited hyperlinks in the moment when it is being clicked.
  But this cannot be true, because changing the style later would NOT change the color of previously clicked hyperlinks, which does happen.
  *Therefore this should be wrong.*
- MS Word does NOT remember the visited hyperlinks in a list, but remembers the visit of the hyperlink inside the cell.
  But when closing the document, I am not asked whether to save it, which means the document has not changed.
  *Therefore this should be wrong.*
- ... ?

Can somebody tell me how it actually works?
Is there a list of visited hyperlinks that I could clear?

Comment: I have no idea where such a list is maintained but suspect it is a Windows or operating system function, because this is also true in all browsers AFAIK. In Word, you can modify the style Followed Hyperlink to have the same color as an unfollowed hyperlink.

Comment: Why is my question opinion-based? I'm NOT asking for opinions, but for an explanation how it works, and I gave some possible answers how it could work.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon yes I already did that. But I would like to know how it works behind the scenes. Changing colours is just a workaround in my opinion.

Comment: I voted to open the question. That said, I do not think this is a Word or office feature but something having to do with the nature of hyperlinks universally. The same thing happens in any browser and in pdf.

Comment: (1) This would be a better question if you described in more detail what behavior you’re seeing, and in what version of Word (i.e., clarify what you’re asking) and said what you’ve done to find the answer yourself.  (2) I suspect that your third guess is about right — but why do you use the word “cell”?  It seems to me that Word retains the “visited” status of the link ‘‘in memory’’, although not in a way that causes it to be written to the document.  ... (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Here’s what I tried (in Word 2013):  (a) Create a Word document, put a link into it, and visit the link (with Ctrl+click).  (b) THEN save the document, and close it.  (c) Reopen the document. … The link is blue again.  So it seems like the way to clear the status of all hyperlinks is to close and reopen the document. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Do you want to be able to reset links individually?  (3) If that’s what you want, you can do it by editing the link.  Click in the link (or move your cursor there with the arrow keys), type `x` and Backspace, and move away.